# 500:Internal Server Error while sending Post Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, postman, internal-server-error

This is the implementation class to get Token but while i am making a POST call its throwing me Internal Server Error,
Could anyone help me out on this

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("client_id", "clientId");
    map.add("tenant_id", "tenantId");
    map.add("client_secret", "clientSecret");
    map.add("scope", "scope");
    map.add("grant_type", "granttype");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Response> response = resttemplate.postForEntity(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/${tokenversion}/token", request, Response.class,tenantId,tokenversion);
    return response.getBody().getAccess_token();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 500 series error means something wrong and unexpected happened  on the server side. The problem is not with your query. You should try to contact microsoft (ie put in a bug report) about this